# React Native App with WordPress REST API - not allowed to create posts as this user

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, api, react-native, wp-api

I'm working on an application in **React Native** with simple **Wordpress backend** using REST API and I didn't have any problems until I used `GET` method.

Now I need to create a blog post using the `POST` method and I'm still getting an error...

What I have:

1. Wordpress with activated Basic Authentication handler plugin -> https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth
2. React Native project with WPAPI Client -> https://github.com/WP-API/node-wpapi

My React code:

```
const WPAPI = require( 'wpapi' );
let apiPromise = WPAPI.discover( 'https://myweb.com/wp-json' ).then(function( site ) {
return site.auth({
    username: 'admin',
    password: 'password'
  }); 
});
apiPromise.then(function( site ) {
    site.posts().create({
      title: 'Your Post Title',
      content: 'Your post content',
      status: 'publish'
    }).then(function( response ) {
        console.log( response );
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      console.log(err);
    });
})
```

and always get this answer:

```
"code": "rest_cannot_create",
"status": 401,
"message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user."
```